# Problems with vertices in blender

Tags: vertices, origin, data-blocks, mirror-modifier

I'm new to the world of Blender and I recently added the Extra Object addon which allows me to add Single Vertices quickly. I was creating a handle starting from the single vertex with the mirror modifier however as I didn't like how it came out I decided to remove the vertices and start from another one. When I added the second vertex it was showing *Vertex.001* instead of *Vertex*. I don't know if that's normal. The problem was that the vertex no longer worked properly (including the mirror modifier) ​​and the point of origin was attached to the vertex slightly away from it. I tried with tutorials but I don't know if it's a bug. Also when I deleted the broken vertex and created another vertex it created copies upon copies of vertexes like vertex 10-11-12. I think I clicked something without meaning to. I have already tried to change all the set origin of the origin point but nothing has changed. I have no idea how to fix it. I really hope I can find the answer here thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you were <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> adding vertices in Object Mode. That way, each vertex is an object in its own right, with its own origin. The numbering system is Blender's standard way of naming newly introduced objects, that you haven't renamed, to avoid name collisions.

Unless told otherwise, the *Mirror* modifier's mirror is through the object origin.

To play with a mesh originating with a single vertex, in **Edit Mode**, options include:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> clicking for automatic extrusion of an edge to the mouse position
- <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> - dragging to extrude edges from a selection of vertices
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicating a selection of vertices
- <kbd>F</kbd> joining vertices with edges, in selection order

.. along with most all the other tools.

Depending on your theme, a vertex can look exactly the same as its object's origin. I guess that could be a gotcha.. it behaves differently, you soon get a sense of it. One option might be to go to 'Object' tab, 'Viewport Display' and switch on 'Axis', until you get used to that.

Answer (score 1):

Blender increments object names with a name format that has `.XXX` appended to the default name like `Cube`, `Cube.001`, `Cube.002`, and so on, to the *Default Cube*. The first time you add a single vertex via *Mesh > Single Vert > Add Single Vert*, the Object and its Object Data (the mesh) are both called *Vert*, the second time you add it, it will be called `Vert.001`. After you delete it, any [`Data-Blocks`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html) used in the object (if no more object is referencing it) gets thrown into [`Orphan Data`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html).

> **Orphan Data** = Lists data-blocks which are unused and/or will be lost
> when the file is reloaded. It includes data-blocks which have only a
> fake user. You can add/remove Fake User by clicking on cross/tick icon
> in the right side of the Outliner editor.

So, the name `Vert` still exists and thus when you add the same type of object again, Blender increments the name to `Vert.001`. If you are sure you don't need this data any longer, you can purge the data using *File > Clean Up > Unused Data-Blocks*. And then it will start again from 0, name `Vert`.

[image]